Why doesn't Marty and Jennifer's time jump to 2015 affect their future in Back to the Future Part II?
In Back to the Future Part II, Marty, Jennifer, and Doc travel directly from 1985 to 2015, essentially "jumping over" the intervening years. This creates a paradox: if they weren't present from 1985 to 2015, how could Marty and Jennifer have gotten married and had kids?
The movie doesn't explicitly address this paradox. It seems to operate on a version of time travel where the act of time traveling doesn't alter the timeline in which they continued to live their lives normally. Thus, the future they visit in 2015 reflects what would have happened if they had stayed in 1985 and lived their lives, even though they actually traveled through time.
In other words, the movie implies that the timeline remains intact and unaffected by their time travel, even though, logically, their absence from 1985 to 2015 should have impacted their futures. This can be interpreted as the film using a version of time-travel logic where paradoxes are ignored for the sake of the plot.
Why doesn't Marty and Jennifer's time jump to 2015 affect their future in Back to the Future Part II?

You assume that they traveled to the future and did not return.

@MarcWilson - It's a completely fair question. While they're in the future, it's as if they disappeared from their current timeline and appeared elsewhere. The future they go to should be one in which they mysteriously went missing.

@Valorum No, they were missing just for one day, between the morning they left to 2015 with Doc till that evening very late, when they returned from 2015 to the wrong 1985. But as Doc has explained, when the book was destroyed, the 1985 where Jennifer was left sleeping on her porch became the "almost old" 1985, except that Marty having gone to 1955 (and then 1885) after leaving her there, was absent for a few hours, and only returned from 1885 just a bit later and was there when she woke up.

@Alfred - Until they got back, they were mysteriously missing. Once they'd returned, they weren't any more. We know that it takes a while for changes to echo up and down the various timelines.

In the first film Marty changes the course of his parent's meeting. Despite this creating an obvious grandfather paradox, the reverberations from his actions take multiple days to catch up with him. This is evidently a fictional universe which is somewhat resistant to instantaneous changes to the timeline.
We could posit that had Marty and Co. not returned to the present, that the future would have eventually shifted around them.

We might speculate that 2015 Marty and Jennifer lived the 1980s experiences with the their Delorean round-trip to 2015 and saw Doc's later steam engine time machine, so at the very least, Jennifer should have anticipated the visit from her 1985 self, yet seemed oblivious in the moment.

At the end of Back to the Future Part III, Marty is back in 1985 and finds Jennifer sleeping on her porch. There are indeed  a few hours that he did not live the night before in 1985 because he returned from the time he spent in 1955 and 1885 a few hours after the time when he had left her there in 1985. He is biologically a few days older than he was, but still essentially the same young man as he was when he left her there. Wiser, but not visibly older. He will marry Jennifer and have kids with her as in the first version.
It is true that none of them was in 1985 during almost one day, between the time they left with Doc, in the morning, and the time they came back from 2015, in the night. But since they were supposed to go hiking together, nobody noticed it. And the next morning, the Biff of 1985 that did not receive the book, is polishing the car.
But of course they will live together all the years between 1985 and 2015, even if not exactly as in the original situation. The versions who went to 2015 in the DeLorean did not stay there. Their older versions whom they met, the ones that really belonged to 2015, lived a somewhat different life (the one where Marty did have the accident), so they did not "remember" a trip to 2015 they did not make.
Their future in 2015 is indeed somewhat impacted : the wiser Marty did not have the car accident, and has probably a much better life than in the first version. In particular he will have no need to get into Needles' shady scheme and therefore is not fired, so the printout Jennifer holds is blank and does not have the word FIRED on it.

Time travel is inherently inconsistent
With the exception of traveling to the future by way of flying away at high speeds and returning back, all time travel is stuffed with paradoxes and inconsistencies which become apparent upon tenacious analysis. The one in question is no exception.
Like any movie plot with time travel to the future and back involved (strictly speaking, where travel to the past is involved), this one isn't supposed to be making perfect sense when examined under magnifying glass. It is only supposed to create first impression of sort-of consistency sufficient enough for you to enjoy the movie. This one does it pretty well for the overwhelming majority of punters.
